# How to subtract time values formatted as "HH:mm"?

Tags: time-date

I want to subtract time values like `12:04` from `11:30` and get *34 minutes* or *0:34*.

I tried to achieve this using calculations like

```el
(time-subtract 
 (parse-time-string "12:04") 
 (parse-time-string "11:30"))
```

This way I get the error `Invalid time specification`.

OK. Maybe I need to encode times first:

```el
(time-subtract 
 (apply #'encode-time (parse-time-string "12:04"))
 (apply #'encode-time (parse-time-string "11:30")))
```

Now I get the error `Wrong type argument: fixnump, nil`.

Is there a way to subtract times without having to calculate total minutes of both times first like `12 * 60 + 4`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This way I get the error `Invalid time specification`.
>
> OK. Maybe I need to encode times first:

Indeed.

> Now I get the error `Wrong type argument: fixnump, nil`.

This is because `parse-time-string` is documented as returning `nil` for unknown entries, such as those for the date (emphasis mine):

```
parse-time-string is a compiled Lisp function in `parse-time.el'.

(parse-time-string STRING)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 27.1.

Parse the time in STRING into (SEC MIN HOUR DAY MON YEAR DOW DST TZ).
STRING should be an ISO 8601 time string, e.g., "2020-01-15T16:12:21-08:00",
or something resembling an RFC 822 (or later) date-time, e.g.,
"Wed, 15 Jan 2020 16:12:21 -0800".  This function is
somewhat liberal in what format it accepts, and will attempt to
return a "likely" value even for somewhat malformed strings.
The values returned are identical to those of `decode-time', but
any unknown values other than DST are returned as nil, and an
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
unknown DST value is returned as -1.
```

For example:

```el
(parse-time-string "12:04")
;; => (0 4 12 nil nil nil nil -1 nil)
```

This result cannot be handled directly by other time functions, so those `nil`s need filling in.  Emacs 27 introduced the handy utility function `decoded-time-set-defaults` for this purpose:

```
decoded-time-set-defaults is a compiled Lisp function in `time-date.el'.

(decoded-time-set-defaults TIME &optional DEFAULT-ZONE)

Set any nil values in `decoded-time' TIME to default values.
The default value is based on January 1st, 1970 at midnight.

TIME is modified and returned.
```

Behold:

```el
(decoded-time-set-defaults (parse-time-string "12:04"))
;; => (0 4 12 1 1 0 nil -1 nil)
```

Putting it all together (note that the new calling convention of `encode-time` accepts a decoded time as a single list argument):

```el
(require 'time-date)

(defun my-mins-between (time1 time2)
  "Return the minutes between HH:mm strings TIME1 and TIME2."
  (let ((diff (apply #'time-subtract
                     (mapcar (lambda (time)
                               (encode-time (decoded-time-set-defaults
                                             (parse-time-string time))))
                             (list time1 time2)))))
    (/ (float-time diff) 60)))

(my-mins-between "12:04" "11:30")
;; => 34.0
```

Or you can declare technical bankruptcy and rely on Org parsing functions instead.  Since Org 9.1:

```el
(- (org-duration-to-minutes "12:04")
   (org-duration-to-minutes "11:30"))
;; => 34.0
```

In older Org versions:

```el
(- (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes "12:04")
   (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes "11:30"))
;; => 34

(- (org-duration-string-to-minutes "12:04")
   (org-duration-string-to-minutes "11:30"))
;; => 34
```

---

**References**

- [`(info "(elisp) Time of Day")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) Time Conversion")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Conversion.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) Time Parsing")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) Time Calculations")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Calculations.html)

Comment: Thanks @Basil! parsing time is one of the corners of elisp that always trips me up. This is a very helpful explanation

Comment: Alas! In GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32):


Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid time specification")
  encode-time((0 30 11 1 1 0 nil -1 nil))
  (lambda (time) (encode-time (decoded-time-set-defaults (parse-time-string time))))("11:30")
  mapcar((lambda (time) (encode-time (decoded-time-set-defaults (parse-time-string time)))) ("11:30" "12:04"))

Comment: I declare technical bankruptcy! :-) The best answer for me is (- (org-duration-to-minutes "12:04")
   (org-duration-to-minutes "11:30"))
;; => 34.0

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov If `encode-time` doesn't work as intended for you, then please try Emacs 27.2, and either way consider reporting it upstream via `M-x report-emacs-bug RET`.

Comment: @Basil Thank you for encouraging me to upgrade! It's the bleeding edge for me: GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32). But the problem persists:
```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid time specification")
  encode-time((0 30 11 1 1 0 nil -1 nil))
```
Are you sure it's a bug?

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov I'm not 100% sure, but the information collected by `report-emacs-bug` and a reproducible recipe will help us be certain. TIA.

Comment: @Basil OK, I sent the bug report with the text function and 4 lines of the stack trace.

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov For posterity, here it is: https://bugs.gnu.org/48290.  I don't see the stack trace though, or any explanation other than the subject ;).

Comment: @Basil I've sent 2 letters as a bug report, because the first one didn't contain any useful information but generated content. So thank you for merging both my letters together. I see that soon your function `my-mins between` will work properly because `decoded-time-set-defaults` will set the default year 1970 instead of 0 in a future release. Am I correct?

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov You can send further information to the same bug address, you don't need to send a new bug report each time. Just email 48298@debbugs.gnu.org with your comments.

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov Have you tried whether `(encode-time '(0 30 11 1 1 1970 nil -1 nil))` works for you? If it does, then you are correct in that `my-mins-between` will work as intended in Emacs 28. Until you are able to use Emacs 28, users of `decoded-time-set-defaults` will have to work around its bug.

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov If `(encode-time '(0 30 11 1 1 1970 nil -1 nil))` works on your system, then please respond to the bug report thread so that we know. Thanks again.

Comment: @Basil Yes, it works! `(encode-time '(0 30 11 1 1 1970 nil -1 nil))` yielded `(0 30600)`

Comment: @Basil I tried to respond to the bug report discussion, but seem to fail again. First I sent the reply to you only, then I sent to 48298@debbugs.gnu.org which is probably OK, but I broke the replies chain.

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov It's fine, as long as you `To:` or `Cc:` the bug address, there's no problem. Your message shows up now: https://bugs.gnu.org/48298#57